# Use default back button in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't know how to make a navigation controller use the default `<` button. The only way I know how to add a back button at all is to add a `Bar Button Item` but there I have to provide the image myself. I want to use the default system back symbol, the kind that shows up with show/push segue. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like it *can be done* with **Navigation Controller** -  no need to explicitly A) add a button, B) nor hook it up to *go back*.  Here's another great video tutorial from Swift Guy for how to get that going: [How To Use The Navigation Controller In Xcode 8 (Swift 3.0)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XARzl84FZW0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about doing this when presenting a view controller modally. You can't add get the < as you would in a push segue because Apple decided to just not build it in (as far as I know). Your best bet is to create a left bar button item with the text "<" or create your own back button and set it to that image to give your app some uniqueness!

Answer (score 2):

i guess we can't use < by default. we need to add < image.
i think you should create a class Basecontroller and inherit all classes from this. and write this code in that class, so you don't need to add < image to all controller. just set image in only one class.

```
class BaseController: UIViewControlller {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_indicator")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_indicator")
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: i was doing the same, but i have a problem when you want to include the pageviewcontroller, since BaseController already inherits from UIViewController, it cannot be used with PageViewController