# Back Button Left Alignment IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to left align back button **i.e** remove the space on the left of the back arrow . Using a custom back button .

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrow03"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back")

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Tried to use negative width for the button as suggested in the below SO link but it didnt work. 
[How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios)

**Image**

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrEO2.jpg

Please help.

Comment: beacuse in example they are assigning to  leftbarbutton instead of backBarButton . i think you should try  answer 2   in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114423/use-default-back-button-in-navigation-controller/36114624#36114624.
if you want same image on back bar button for every controller.

Comment: thanks @SahilBeri let me try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Refer below code to implement back button on left alignment.**

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton (type: UIButtonType.Custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageName"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

**Note -** Make sure your image has to be plain ( transparent ) background.

```
func backButtonPressed(btn : UIButton) {

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

---

**Swift 4 Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button: UIButton = UIButton (type: UIButtonType.custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageName"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("backButtonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

---

```
func backButtonPressed(btn : UIButton) {

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thanks .. tried the code the image is aligned now. But its crashing on clicking back button? any workarounds?

Comment: Check action: "backButtonPressed" has to be same name.